# Complex hilbert space and its complex conjugate vector space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ be a complex Hilbert space, and $\overline{V}$ its conjugate vector space (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_vector_space)

What are sufficient conditions such that $V \cong \overline{V}$. Is it always true? If not, can you provide a counterexample?

On the wikipedia page, it is written that $V$ and $\overline{V}$ are isomorphic vector spaces, because they have the same dimension. It seems that this argument only works when the spaces are finite dimensional.

Comment: In the infinite dimensional case the equality of the cardinality of the bases also gives you isomorphism. Write the spaces as products of separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces (or what is the same factors with countable Hilbert-space bases). The cardinality of the number of factors will have to be the same. Then map each factor to a factor of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are isomorphic.  But not canonically isomorphic.

Again, this is because they have the same "dimension", where now "dimension" is the "[Hilbert dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Hilbert_dimension)": the cardinality of a maximal orthonormal set.

Comment: Does this mean that every hilbert space is isomorphic to its dual? Because I proved that $\overline{V} \cong V*$, and from what you said it would follow that $V \cong V^*$

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 1):

Let the map $\varphi:\mathcal{H}\to\overline{\mathcal{H}}$ from a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ into its complex conjugate $\overline{\mathcal{H}}$ be antilinear. Then 
$$\varphi(x+y)=\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)\hspace{0.2cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.2cm}\varphi(\alpha x)=\overline{\alpha}\varphi(x)$$
for all $x,y\in\mathcal{H}$. This map is also a homomorphism between $(\mathcal{H},\cdot)$ and $(\overline{\mathcal{H}},*)$ where $\alpha *x=\overline{\alpha}\cdot x$. Next define the map $\psi:\overline{\mathcal{H}}\to\mathcal{H}$ by $\psi(x):=\varphi^{-1}(x)$ for all $x\in\overline{\mathcal{H}}$. Then $\psi$ is an antilinear map as well since
$$\psi(x+y)=\varphi^{-1}(x+y)=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x')+\varphi(y'))=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x'+y'))=x'+y'$$ 
where we used the antilinearity of $\varphi$. But
$$x'+y'=\varphi^{-1}\varphi(x')+\varphi^{-1}\varphi(y')=\varphi^{-1}(x)+\varphi^{-1}(y)=\psi(x)+\psi(y)$$
hence $$\psi(x+y)=\psi(x)+\psi(y)$$
Similarly we have for the second property
$$\psi(\alpha*x)=\varphi^{-1}(\alpha*x)=\varphi^{-1}(\overline{\alpha}\cdot x)=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(\alpha\cdot x))=\alpha\cdot x$$
thus $\psi$ is as well a homomorphism. Therefore any antilinear map $\varphi$ is a isomorphism between the algebraic structures $(\mathcal{H},\cdot)$ and  $(\overline{\mathcal{H}},*)$. So they must be isomorphic as vector spaces as well since vector spaces are algebraic structures themselves.

Comment: You show they are isomorphic as real vector spaces.  Not as complex vector spaces, which is what I understood the question to be.  Admittedly, the OP just said $\cong$ without telling us what it means.

Comment: I mean isomorphic as complex vector spaces. It is trivial that they are isomorphic as real vector spaces, because conjugation on reals doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think it is sufficient to show that they are isomorphic as algebraic structures which implies their isomorphism as complex vector spaces. Because isomorphism of algebraic structures preserves their respective scalar multiplication operation.

Comment: @GEdgar corrected it. you were right. so essentially it is sufficient to construct any antilinear map.

Comment: @Arian How did you know that $\varphi^{-1}$ exists (as a function)? Correct me if I misunderstood you, but didn't you just assume that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism? It could very well be the constant zero map.